# Why doesn't numpy.random and multiprocessing play nice?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, multiprocessing

I have a random walk function, that uses `numpy.random` to do the random step.
The function `walk`, by itself, works just fine.  In parallel, it works as expected in most cases, however in conjunction with `multiprocessing`, it fails.
Why does `multiprocessing` get it wrong?

```
import numpy as np

def walk(x, n=100, box=.5, delta=.2):
    "perform a random walk"
    w = np.cumsum(x + np.random.uniform(-delta,delta,n))
    w = np.where(abs(w) > box)[0]
    return w[0] if len(w) else n

N = 10

# run N trials, all starting from x=0
pwalk = np.vectorize(walk)
print pwalk(np.zeros(N))

# run again, using list comprehension instead of ufunc
print [walk(0) for i in range(N)]

# run again, using multiprocessing's map
import multiprocessing as mp
p = mp.Pool()
print p.map(walk, [0]*N)
```

The results, are typically something like...

```
[47 16 72  8 15  4 38 52 12 41]
[7, 45, 25, 13, 16, 19, 12, 30, 23, 4]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 14, 3, 14]
```

The first two methods obviously show randomness, while the latter doesn't.
What's going on, so that `multiprocessing` doesn't get it right?

If you add a `sleep` so it's a `sleepwalk` and there's significant delay, `multiprocessing` still gets it wrong.

However, if you replace the call to `np.random.uniform` with a non-array method like `[(random.random()-.5) for i in range(n)]`, then it works as expected.

So why doesn't `numpy.random` and `multiprocessing` play nice?

Comment: my guess is that numpy is seeding its random number generator with the same value every time it is initialized, and thus all of the child processes are on the same point on the randomness graph and will generate the same set of random numbers. try calling ``numpy.random.seed`` and passing it some value that will vary between calls to walk non-deterministically (such as the current system time) at the start of your walk.

Comment: maybe, but then I'd expect all the last row to be the same… and that's not exactly the case.

Comment: See also [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/briansupport/9ErDidIBBFM)

Comment: Huh… interesting.  And seems to have been asked already.  Oops.

Comment: @aruisdante: you basically answered my question… not what do I do, but why is it doing what it is doing… so I'd give you the check if I could.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns No worries. I only write Answers if either I'm a) 100% sure of the solution, or b) Can test the solution to satisfy (a). Since neither was true, I wrote it as a comment. Glad it helped.

Comment: I had a similar issue and realized it's because `numpy.random` uses the same seed in every process, but `random` does not.  Since I was using both, my results were always almost the same but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 13):

> What's going on, so that multiprocessing doesn't get it right?

You need to [reseed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) in each process to make sure the pseudo-random streams are independent of one another.

I use [*os.urandom*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.urandom) to generate the seeds.

Comment: `np.random.seed(int.from_bytes(os.urandom(4), byteorder='little'))` in python 3.